# MalformedInputException, what's wrong with this url?

Tags: java, scala, url

I want to fetch this dirty url: `http://relevancy.bger.ch/php/clir/http/index.php?highlight_docid=atf%3A%2F%2F115-IV-187%3Ade&lang=de&type=show_document`

After some time, I have eventually found this solution.

```
val link = "http://relevancy.bger.ch/php/clir/http/index.php?highlight_docid=" +
        java.net.URLEncoder.encode("atf://115-IV-187:de", "UTF-8") + "&lang=" +
        java.net.URLEncoder.encode("de", "UTF-8") + "&type=" +
        java.net.URLEncoder.encode("show_document", "UTF-8")
```

When I print it, I can click on it from the terminal and the page opens in the browser. But I get a `MalformedInputException` in the following code.

```
println(scala.io.Source.fromURL(link).mkString)
```

**Update**

The exception says:

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:210)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
at scala.io.BufferedSource.mkString(BufferedSource.scala:94)
at services.Downloader$.getAtf(Downloader.scala:47)
at controllers.JudgmentController.$anonfun$bot$1(JudgmentController.scala:71)
at scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:52)
at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:188)
at play.api.mvc.ActionRefiner.$anonfun$invokeBlock$3(Action.scala:522)
at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:302)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:38)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:43)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: show the output of the println()

Comment: The exception should be followed by a message. Print it here along with the entire stack trace.

Comment: I would say that the problem is with the document, not the URL.  Maybe the document is corrupted?  Maybe its actual encoding doesn't match what Scala is using (assuming?) to decode it?

Comment: @StephenC You are right, The problem was not where I was looking. By the way. The solution was already given on the page mentioned on the top of the page. I am sorry for the unnecessary question.